# Number of iterations for minimal cost complexity prunning?

Tags: decision-trees

I've been fiddling with weka's J48 decision tree implementation (C4.5). My goal is to implement cost complexity prunning using weakest link cut method. Basically my algorithm iteratively prunes the tree creating trees with fewer nodes from the previous ones ($ T_0 > T_1 > T_2 >...>T_N$).

My goal now is how do I find that $N$ from $T_N$ meaning how many times should I prune the tree. The algorithm seems to prune pretty aggressively, few iterations too much and it will be completely prunned.

For now I'm using the stop condition regarding the complexity factor and I stop the prunning when $\alpha \gt 0.001$ (from $R(t) = R(t) + \alpha|T|$) . This works pretty well for the two datasets I've tested so far but I wouldn't bet my money on it.